# Find the $z$ such that $|z + a| \leq |z| + |a|\cos(\arg(z))$

Tags: complex, inequalities, resolve

Find the $z$ such that $|z + a| \leq |z| + |a|\cos(\arg(z))$. My approach is to use `Resolve`:

```
With[{\[Theta] = Arg[z]},
 Resolve[
  ForAll[z, Abs[z + 1] <= Abs[z] + Cos[\[Theta]]]]]
```

but the result I get is: `False` with a warning: `Warning: Resolve used FunctionExpand to transform the system. Since \ FunctionExpand transformation rules are only generically correct, the \ solution set might have been altered`

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: The warning message makes me think `Reduce[Abs[z+a]<=Abs[z]+Abs[a]Cos[Arg[z]],z]`

Comment: How will omitting the ForAll affect the result?

Comment: `Reduce` should give a list of one or more solutions and that are not just "generically correct." That was the first thing I was trying to overcome. If you are looking for some solution in  `z` that makes this true for all cases then it may require some thinking. But whatever the answer from `Reduce` is, I am hoping it will not be that `Reduce` has no method to solve this and that whatever it returns will give you some more insight into your problem. Does that explain my thinking?

Comment: I just get back the same inequality. Are there general methods to get a solution out of mathematica, or is it unlikely to help in this case?

Comment: I had hoped Reduce might at least partly crack the problem. Transcendental problems and mixed algebraic with transcendental problems and Abs and Max,Min, etc tend to make solutions less likely. By inspection of your problem, if z>=0 then I think the inequality is true, if z<0&&a<0 then the inequality is false, if z<0&&0<a<abs(z) then it is true, otherwise I think it is false. Check each of those general cases and each of the edge cases carefully and don't trust me.

Comment: I think in general we can show the opposite inequality: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286167/upper-bound-on-modulus-of-complex-number-plus-a-real-number/4286233#4286233

Comment: You can write `Re[z]/Abs[z]` in place of `Cos[Abs[z]]` to avoid the warning. Indeed, $|z|\cos\arg z =\Re(z)$, so you got MMA a little dizzy rewriting $\cos\arg z \to \Re(z)/|z|$. It still holds in the limit $z\to 0$, provided the convention that $\arg 0 = 0$, but still technically singular. The warning itself is harmless; MMA knows that `Arg[0]` is 0. But the full problem (that for an unconstrained $a\in\mathbb{C}$, not $1$ in its place that you've started with) is indeed tough. Are there any constraints that can be put on the $a$?

Comment: If I flip the inequality so that I have: `ForAll[z, Abs[z + 1] <= Abs[z] + Cos[Arg[z]]]` then I get `True` as the result

Comment: Thanks @kkm, let's say that `a=1`

Comment: Then the solution is obviously all $z\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Wait, is $a$ real?

Comment: I had meant to specify that `a` is real

Comment: “If I flip the inequality...” -- you forgot `Complexes`!

Comment: @kkm I thought Mathematica solved over the complex numbers by default. Also I get the same result (`True`) if I specify `Complexes`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`ForAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ForAll.html) and [`Resolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Resolve.html) is incorrect to state a problem like this. They are useful for proving statements that hold in general, but the problem in the title of your question asks for the specific values of $z$ satisfying an equation. [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Refuce.html) is a much better tool for it.

What you wrote was, essentially, $$\forall(z):|z+1|\le|z|+\cos\arg z$$
The statement is patently false: the equality holds only for $\cos\theta = 1$, which is true only for $\theta = 0$, i.e. real $z$, but not *all* $z$.

Since $|z|\cos\arg z=\Re(z)$, you got MMA a little dizzy rewriting $\cos\arg z \to \Re(z)/|z|$. It holds in the limit $z\to 0$, provided the convention that $\arg 0 = 0$, but is still technically singular. I think this is what the warning is about. It's harmless, and you can safely ignore it; MMA knows that `Arg[0]` is $0$. If you do the rewrite yourself, handling the corner case of $z=0$, you get back a solid `False` without any warnings:

```
Resolve[ForAll[z, z == 0 || Abs[z + 1] <= Abs[z] + Re[z]/Abs[z]], Complexes]

Out[...]= False
```

But I assume that your goal was to find the $z$ satisfying the inequality, and `Reduce` is what you want. Either of:

```
Reduce[z == 0 || Abs[z + 1] <= Abs[z] + Cos[Arg[z]], z, Complexes] // Simplify
Reduce[z == 0 || Abs[z + 1] <= Abs[z] + Re[z]/Abs[z], z, Complexes] // Simplify
```

which produce an identical result, the former with the same warning, the latter without. The evaluation result is a fancy way of saying "only real $z$ except $-1 \lt z \lt 0$ are the solutions", but I could not torture a more sensible simplified form out of MMA:

```
Out[...]= z == 0 || (Im[z] == 0 && (Re[z] <= -1 || Re[z] > 0))
```

Without the manual handling of the case $z=0$, the solution computed by MMA does not include it, whatever I tried: note the strict inequality `Re[z] > 0` in the answer. It's important to remember to not just slap `z == 0 ||` on the condition; this requires a separate treatment of the excluded case to work out whether $z=0$ is in fact a solution—it's included by the MMA into its answer *because I told it so*, not because it's truth value had been inferred (and MMA in fact fails to infer it), so the proof is on me when I added the `z == 0 ||` term. It is indeed true, as substituting $z=0$ into your the full inequality $|z+1| \le |z| + \cos \arg z$ reduces it to a trivially true one $1\le1$.

---

Now, the answer produced by `Reduce` to your full problem (with an arbitrary $a\in\mathbb{R}$) is quite involved. Below is the correct way to state your problem, resulting in a *nearly* correct answer. If you omit [`Complexes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complexes.html), MMA will assume that $z$ is real; if you do not specify [`Element[a, Reals]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html), it will assume that $a$ is also complex and will fail to solve it. [`LogicalExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogicalExpand.html) is a common way to convert the $\mathtt{Reduce}$'s output to the normal form, which makes the most sense when the output is a mess of nested Boolean terms, and is a very common and useful pattern.

```
Reduce[Abs[z + a] <= Abs[z] + Abs[a] Cos[Arg[z]] && Element[a, Reals],
       z, Complexes] // LogicalExpand

Out[...]= 
  (a == 0 && Re[z] > 0) ||
  (a == 0 && Re[z] < 0) ||
  (Re[z] >= -(a/4) && a < 0) ||
  (a == 0 && Re[z] == 0 && Im[z] != 0) ||
  (Im[z] == 0 && a > 0 && Re[z] > 0) ||
  (Im[z] == 0 && a > 0 && Re[z] <= -a) ||
  (0 < Re[z] && a < 0 && Re[z] < -(a/4) && 
     Im[z] <= 2 Sqrt[-(Re[z]^3/(a + 4 Re[z]))] &&
     -2 Sqrt[-(Re[z]^3/(a + 4 Re[z]))] <= Im[z])
```

I split the output into lines for readability. The last disjunctive term of the solution is quite *interesting*, and is likely what you're looking for; the 3rd line `(Re[z] >= -(a/4) && a < 0)` is also probably notable.

However, just like the simplified case with the special point $z=0$, **MMA fails to include it into the solution.** Substituting $z=0$ into the original inequality $|z+a|\le|z|+|a|\cos\arg z$ reduces it to the trivially true $|a|<=|a|$, but the `Reduce` result above doesn't account for it!

```
Reduce[Abs[z + a] <= Abs[z] + Abs[a] Cos[Arg[z]] && Element[a, Reals],
       z, Complexes] /. z -> 0 // Simplify
Out[...]= False
```

Looks like a bug in MMA (still there as of 13.1). The rewrite rule  $\cos\arg z \to \Re(z)/ |z|$ is not valid for $z=0$, as its RHS is singular, while the LHS is defined, albeit conventionally. Indeed, there is a simple way to get the correct results by adding the term explicitly:

```
Reduce[z == 0 || Abs[z + a] <= Abs[z] + Abs[a] Cos[Arg[z]] &&
       Element[a, Reals], z, Complexes] /. z -> 0 // Simplify
Out[...]= True
```

Indeed, there appears to be a persistent bug in MMA to watch for.

Answer (score 4):

Here we test the case which `a` is not a real number for example `a=1+I`

```
With[{a = 1 + I}, 
 ComplexContourPlot[
  Abs[z] + Abs[a]*Cos[Arg[z]] - Abs[z + a], {z, -5 - 5 I, 5 + 5 I}, 
  Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> {None, Red}]]
With[{a = 1 + I}, 
 ComplexRegionPlot[
  Abs[z + a] <= Abs[z] + Abs[a]*Cos[Arg[z]], {z, -5 - 5 I, 5 + 5 I}]]
```

[image]

And thanks @kkm the ideas that we can replace `Cos[Arg[z]]` by `Re[z]/Abs[z]` to verify the above region.

```
sol = With[{a = 1 + I}, 
  Reduce[Abs[z + a] <= Abs[z] + Abs[a]*Re[z]/Abs[z], z]]
ComplexRegionPlot[sol, {z, -5 - 5 I, 5 + 5 I}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]